# How do I change the date format?

Tags: mac, settings

It's currently displaying "Fri Sep 10 9:43 AM" I changed it in System Preferences to [WeekName][Day][Month][Year] then restarted the computer but, it didn't change anything.

I'm using a 2013 MacBook Pro running MacOS 11.5.2

[image]